# Data selection by comparing elements from different sublists in a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a huge nested list in the following general format:

$\textrm{originaltab} = \{e_i^j\} = \{\{e_1^1,e_1^2,e_1^3,e_1^4,e_1^5,e_1^6,e_1^7,e_1^8\},\{e_2^1,e_2^2,e_2^3,e_2^4,e_2^5,e_2^6,e_2^7,e_2^8\},\cdots\}$

with 8 elements per sublist and a total of around 1,000,000 sublists in the nested list $\textrm{originaltab}$.

What I need to do is the following:

1) Sort the sublists by increasing values of the elements $e_i^3$. This is easy to do using the command Sort in Mathematica:

```
Sort[originaltab, #1[[3]] < #2[[3]] &]
```

2) Now I need to define a new nested list, let me call it $\textrm{newtab}$, which consists of all the sublists in $\textrm{originaltab}$ satisfying the following criteria:

$(e_i^1 \neq e_j^1 \, || \, e_i^2 \neq e_j^2) \,\&\& \, (e_j^3\in [e_i^3-\epsilon,e_i^3+\epsilon] \,\&\& \, e_j^4\in [e_i^4-\delta,e_i^4+\delta]),\, i\neq j$

where $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are some small positive numbers. Since I sorted the sublists in $\textrm{originaltab}$ such that they are ordered by increasing values of $e_i^3$, the sublists in $\textrm{originaltab}$ which eventually satisfy the above criteria are necessarily close to each other, such that it would be a waste of time to compare the first sublist in $\textrm{originaltab}$ with the last one, because they will obviously not satisfy the above criteria, since $e_{1000000}^3-e_1^3\gg\epsilon$. The sublists in $\textrm{newtab}$ should be sorted as in the case of $\textrm{originaltab}$.

3) Once I have defined $\textrm{newtab}$, as schematically depicted above, I need to define a new nested list, which I will call $\textrm{auxiliarytab}$, which should be composed as follows: for all the sublists in $\textrm{newtab}$ satisfying $(e_j^3\in [e_i^3-\epsilon,e_i^3+\epsilon] \,\&\& \, e_j^4\in [e_i^4-\delta,e_i^4+\delta])$, we should delete the ones with the highest value of $e_j^5$. This deletion should be immediate, preventing an excluded sublist to be called again to be compared with other sublists (in the case of overlapping zones).

4) Once the step 3 above is done, I need to remove from originaltab the set of sublists contained in $\textrm{auxiliarytab}$. This is easy to do using the command Complement in Mathematica:

```
finaltab = Complement[originaltab, auxiliarytab]
```

So, as a very simple illustration of what the algorithm should do, consider the example below, with $\epsilon=0.1$:

```
originaltab = {{0.3,0.1,50,0,200,0,0,0},{0.4,0.2,50.1,0,600,0,0,0},{0.3,0.2,50.2,0,10,0,0,0},{1.5,0.8,50.3,0,230,0,0,0},{0.1,0.9,123,0,3000,0,0,0}}

newtab = {{0.3,0.1,50,0,200,0,0,0},{0.4,0.2,50.1,0,600,0,0,0},{0.3,0.2,50.2,0,10,0,0,0},{1.5,0.8,50.3,0,230,0,0,0}}

auxiliarytab = {{0.3,0.1,50,0,200,0,0,0},{0.3,0.2,50.2,0,10,0,0,0}}

finaltab = {{0.4,0.2,50.1,0,600,0,0,0},{1.5,0.8,50.3,0,230,0,0,0},{0.1,0.9,123,0,3000,0,0,0}}
```

How could I do steps 2 and 3 above in a efficient way (remember that the actual situation comprises a nested list with around 1,000,000 sublists!)?

I thank in advance for any possible suggestion!

========================

EDIT: below I give a possible way of doing what I want, but this way is extremely inefficient in terms of computation time and memory usage. It is simply infeasible if originaltab has 1,000,000 sublists (but works well for a nested list with just 2,000 sublists, for instance).

```
Clear[\[Epsilon],\[Delta],originaltab,auxiliarytab,finaltab]
\[Epsilon]=0.1;
\[Delta]=0.1;
originaltab=Sort[{{0.3,0.1,50,0,200,0,0,0},{0.4,0.2,50.1,0,600,0,0,0},{0.3,0.2,50.2,0,10,0,0,0},{1.5,0.8,50.3,0,230,0,0,0},{0.1,0.9,123,0,3000,0,0,0}},#1[[3]]<#2[[3]]&]
auxiliarytab=Sort[DeleteDuplicates[DeleteMissing[Flatten[Table[
  If[(originaltab[[i, 1]] != originaltab[[j, 1]] || 
      originaltab[[i, 2]] != 
       originaltab[[j, 2]]) && (IntervalMemberQ[
       Interval[{originaltab[[i, 3]] - \[Epsilon], 
         originaltab[[i, 3]] + \[Epsilon]}], 
       originaltab[[j, 3]]] && 
      IntervalMemberQ[
       Interval[{originaltab[[i, 4]] - \[Delta], 
         originaltab[[i, 4]] + \[Delta]}], originaltab[[j, 4]]]),
   DeleteCases[{originaltab[[i, All]], originaltab[[j, All]]},
    {_, _, _, _, 
     Max@{originaltab[[i, 5]], originaltab[[j, 5]]}, _, _, _}
    ], Missing[]],
  {i, 1, Length[originaltab] - 1}, {j, i + 1, 
   Length[originaltab]}], 2]]], #1[[3]] < #2[[3]] &]
finaltab=Sort[Complement[originaltab,auxiliarytab],#1[[3]]<#2[[3]]&]
```

Comment: Add your list examples as Mathematica code, not as images, so people can play with them more easily. Also, when you do the sorting / selecting in a naive way, without any special tricks, is it really too slow? I wouldn't want to optimize something that doesn't need optimizing...

Comment: Hi, sorting the sublists by increasing values of their third elements is not the issue. But comparing the sublists in the way described in the question may be infeasible in terms of computation time if we naively compare each sublist with the other ones. This would give $k!/2!/(k - 2)!$ combinations, with k = 1,000,000. This is why the comparisons / selections should be done with just "nearby" sublists, with "nearby" being defined by the numbers $\epsilon$
and $\delta$ mentioned in the question.

Comment: @stackmath I'm gonna guess your issues come in constructing `axuiliarytab` not in sorting it as `Sort@RandomReal[1, 1000000] // AbsoluteTiming // First` is only about .15 for me. Unless you're doing real-time manipulation and visualization of the data that's not bad at all.

Comment: @MB1965, in fact, the issue is not with the sorting procedure, but with the construction of auxiliarytab. It is extremely time demanding for k = Length[originaltab] = 1,000,000, since the way I implemented it above generates k!/2!/(k-2)! intermediate sublists. For k = 1,000,000 this gives 499,999,500,000 combinations! My notebook cannot handle this computation before running out of memory. A more efficient way of doing this would be to compare just "nearby" sublists, instead of each sublist with all the other ones. But I am struggling to figure out how to do this in Mathematica...

Comment: @stackmath I think we can optimize without worry about "comparing nearby sublists". Let me see if I can knock up a better implementation. I think a more either a functional approach or judicious application of `Compile` should let us handle this.

Comment: @stackmath I put a test implementation [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/eee7df7a-4bdc-4c07-ad65-2df74d9af235). See if that's faster. It's more functional and only tests half as many combinations.

Comment: @MB1965, thank you very much for providing this new implementation. Unfortunately, for some reason I don't understand, it turns out to be slower than the previous implementation. I tested it with a nested list with just 1,940 sublists, and the previous implementation runs in ~ 39s in my notebook, while this new implementation takes ~ 52s to run.

Comment: @stackmath Fascinating. Then the next thing to do is try a Compile. I'll try to get around to that soon if you haven't done it first. One useful thing you might want is the function CompilerFunctions in the Compile context.

Comment: @stackmath Here's a question about your data (I think I have a quick way to window it): what's the general spread on the third column values? Do they clump a lot or is it a smooth distribution?

Comment: @stackmath Also the issue was the `Between` is *a lot* slower than `IntervalMemberQ` for reasons I didn't bother to dig in to.

Comment: @MB1965, in http://oi66.tinypic.com/108aiar.jpg you can see a typical distribution of the points in originaltab, where the vertical axis is the third column and the horizontal axis is the fourth column (which are the main input parameters used for comparisons in constructing auxiliarytab). This picture I uploaded has 19,649 points, but in the actual situation I need to work with ~ 1,000,000 points, and the grid will get much denser (although its shape will remain the same).

Comment: @stackmath Shame, that's way too smooth to generate windows from a naive Split call. Should still be possible to generate the windows before we all with a well-constructed Module / Compile. Could also chunk the data into runs of 10000 and then figure out where the overlaps between runs need to be based on the first and last element of the runs. That might be the easiest thing to do. I'll see if I can't do that at some point today, if you haven't gotten to it first.

Answer (score 2):

So here's the implementation I discussed in my comments. We'll take advantage of a similar `ParallelTable` structure as Ali, but cleaned up a bit, and, here's the crucial bit, we'll restrict the size of our chunks, while making sure nothing slips through the cracks. Here's the data setup:

```
n = 100000;
ot =
  SortBy[#[[3]] &]@
   Transpose@
    {RandomReal[1, n], RandomReal[1, n], RandomReal[100, n],
     ConstantArray[0, n],
     RandomInteger[600, n],
     ConstantArray[0, n], ConstantArray[0, n], ConstantArray[0, n]};
```

And now here's where we figure out which chunks we'll need:

```
chunk = 1000;
cutPoints =
  Riffle[#, # + 1] &@Range[chunk, Length@ot - chunk, chunk];
col = ot[[All, 3]];
chunks =
  Partition[
   Flatten@{
     1,
     Table[
      If[OddQ@i,
       SelectFirst[Range[i, 1, -1], 
        col[[i]] - col[[#]] > \[Epsilon] &],
       SelectFirst[Range[i, Length@col], 
        col[[#]] - col[[i]] > \[Epsilon] &]
       ],
      {i, cutPoints}
      ],
     Length@col
     },
   2
   ];
```

Then we'll adapt the `auxiliarytab` code to work in chunks, rather than all together:

```
auxChunk[{start_, end_}] :=
  Flatten[
   ParallelTable[
    If[(ot[[i, 1]] != ot[[j, 1]] || 
        ot[[i, 2]] != ot[[j, 2]]) && (ot[[i, 3]] - \[Epsilon] <= 
        ot[[j, 3]] <= 
        ot[[i, 3]] + \[Epsilon]) && (ot[[i, 4]] - \[Delta] <= 
        ot[[j, 4]] <= ot[[i, 4]] + \[Delta]),
     MinimalBy[{ot[[i]], ot[[j]]}, #[[5]] &],
     Nothing
     ],
    {i, start, end - 1},
    {j, i + 1, end}
    ],
   2];
```

And then we'll string this together:

```
In[69]:= AbsoluteTiming[
  aut =
    SortBy[
     DeleteDuplicates[
      Join @@ Map[auxChunk, chunks]
      ],
     #[[3]] &
     ];
  ] // First

Out[69]= 287.988
```

Note that this sample is 10x larger than the Ali's version (if I read his code right) but was only just over twice as slow. I cannot promise that 1000 is the best chunk size, you'll obviously want to optimize this. For another reference, on 1904 sublists with chunk size of 100 this takes 1.325 seconds.

Much more interesting problem than I expected (couldn't get away with a simple `Compile` or `PackedArray` solution) -- thanks for that.

#### Performance:

You'll generally want a smaller chunk size, I think, up to a point. The total number of computations will look like:

```
Range[#[[2]] - #[[1]]] & /@ chunks // Total@*Flatten
```

And so in this case we can test out a number of chunk sizes on a test sample of size 100,000:

- Chunks of 500:   49300203  computations
- Chunks of 1000:  72312519  computations
- Chunks of 5000:  270482828 computations
- Chunks of 10000: 519107039 computations

Which would suggest that chunks of 500 are best, but this isn't what we see:

- Chunks of 500:   316 seconds
- Chunks of 1000:  292 seconds
- Chunks of 5000:  472 seconds
- Chunks of 10000: 773 seconds

So yes, smaller chunks are better, but there are also more calls to account for, and this can slow down the process. Also with decreasing chunk size there's a corresponding increase in pre-processing time, so, for instance, while chunks of 1000 are better than chunks of 5000 by a large margin, the benefit from going from 1000 to, say, 750 might be washed out by the extra preprocessing time and extra calls, particularly as the size of `n` increases.

Comment: @AliHashmi Great idea to parallelize. This is really a much smaller boost than what you get from that.

Comment: just curious. how much speed boost do you get when you run the `ParallelTable` with and without chunks for your sample size?

Comment: @AliHashmi Good question. I just retried the 1904 case and got 1.7 seconds all together and .88 seconds chunked. I'll try it on a larger case.

Comment: great ! i am really looking forward to what happens on an input size of 100,000.

Comment: @AliHashmi I just got 57.09 seconds for 10,000 unchunked vs 6.98 chunked. Then 100,000 case will take a while to run.

Comment: my kernel crashed and ran out of memory with the unchunked case with 100000 entries !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial attempt to make your code faster. I would suggest the use of `ParallelTable` and `SortBy` rather than `Sort`. Perhaps in your case there is no need to use `IntervalMemberQ` and `Interval`.

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000, 8}];
(list = SortBy[list, #[[3]] &]); // Timing (* same as originaltab *)

(* {0., Null} *)

(auxiliarytab = 
SortBy[DeleteDuplicates[
  DeleteMissing[
   Flatten[ParallelTable[
     If[(list[[i, 1]] != list[[j, 1]] || 
         list[[i, 2]] != 
          list[[j, 2]]) && (list[[i, 3]] - \[Epsilon] <= 
         list[[j, 3]] <= 
         list[[i, 3]] + \[Epsilon]) && (list[[i, 4]] - \[Delta] <=
          list[[j, 4]] <= list[[i, 4]] + \[Delta]), 
      DeleteCases[{list[[i]], list[[j]]}, {_, _, _, _, 
        Max@{list[[i, 5]], list[[j, 5]]}, _, _, _}], 
      Missing[]], {i, 1, Length[list] - 1}, {j, i + 1, 
      Length[list]}], 2]]], #[[3]] &]); // Timing

(* {117.625, Null} *)

(finaltab = 
SortBy[Complement[list, auxiliarytab], #[[3]] &]); // Timing

(* {0.015625, Null} *)
```

I also checked for 1940 sublists as you mentioned in your comment. Compared to 39 seconds in your case, the modified code gives you ~ 3.84 seconds which is about **10X faster**.

I tried using `SetSharedFunction` to use `Sow` with `ParallelDo` but that implementation was somehow slower and behaving unpredictably.

Hope it helps you partly if not much